# Как отправить несколько исключений в блоке try

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Есть блок try в котором должно возникнуть три исключения. Если возникает первое исключение то управление передается в catch и блок try прерывается, как можно вернутся обратно в блок try и выполнить остальную часть кода?
Дали задачу в условии следующее: 
В программе реализовано три метода в которых искусственно возникает исключение.
Все три метода должны находится в одном блоке try. В блоке должно возникнуть все три исключения(я не знаю как это сделать) и затем обработчики должны обработать каждое возникшие исключение

```
try
{
  method1(); //Здесь всегда возникает исключение
  method2(); //Как выполнить этот код?
  method3(); //И этот?
} 
catch(Exception1 e)
{

}
catch(Exception2 e)
{

}
catch(Exception3 e)
{

}
```

Comment: Этот код вы написали или вам в оригинале его дали?

Comment: Нет здесь все намного упрощенно, не хочу что бы за меня сделали всю задачу, просто прошу подсказки

Comment: Не работают остальные методы(2,3) после исключение! Вот, отличие от метода!

Answer (score 2):

Ок, раз вы не хотите чтоб за вас решили - вот вам подсказка:

Существует блок `try-finally` без `cath`:

```
            try {
                method1();
            } finally {
            }
```

Блок `finally` выполнится всегда, независимо от того было исключение или нет.

UPD. вариант2

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        processExceptions(new Solution());

    }

    public static void processExceptions(Solution obj)
    {

        try {
            obj.method1();
            obj.method2();
            obj.method3();
        }

        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        catch (NoSuchFieldException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public void method1() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }

    public void method2() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        throw new NoSuchFieldException();
    }

    public void method3() throws RemoteException {
        throw new RemoteException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Но в таком случаи в finally придется писать еще один блок try для второго метода-> а в нем еще один finally с try для третьего метода?

Comment: @user176569 да, но фактически условия выполнены - "Все три метода должны находится в одном блоке `try`. В блоке должно возникнуть все три исключения". Про то что еще `try ` нельзя использовать в условии не сказано.

Comment: Не помогло, программа не прошла тестирование

Comment: может вы таки приведете оригинальный текст задачи и возможно там есть пример входных данных и результата работы?

Comment: Условие 
/* Перехват checked исключений
В методе processExceptions обработайте все checked исключения.
Нужно вывести на экран каждое возникшее checked исключение.
Можно использовать только один блок try..
*/

Comment: public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                processExceptions(new Solution());
    
    
        }

        public static void processExceptions(Solution obj)  {
     
            obj.method1();
            obj.method2();
            obj.method3();
        }

Comment: public void method1() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    
        public void method2() throws NoSuchFieldException {
            throw new NoSuchFieldException();
        }

        public void method3() throws RemoteException {
            throw new RemoteException();
        }
    }

Comment: Это меняет дело

Answer (score 2):

Можно через рекурсию и выбор метода с 1 блоком try.

```
private int methodNumber;
public void run(int m) {
    try {
        switch (m) {
            case 0:
                method1();
            case 1:
                method2();
            case 2:
                method3();
        }
    } catch (Exception1 e) {
        System.out.println("Обработка исключения 1");

    } catch (Exception2 e) {
        System.out.println("Обработка исключения 2");

    } catch (Exception3 e) {
        System.out.println("Обработка исключения 3");
    } finally {
        if (methodNumber < METHODS_COUNT) run(++methodNumber);
    }
}
```